# POST request with nodemcu esp8266 to Discord

Tags: discord, http-post, esp8266

I want to translate this code on python:

```
    payload = {
        'content': '!work'
    }
    header ={
        'authorization':'MzkyMzQyNjEzNTasdE5NjI2.XuK7Ow.JWZZcbEoObXxPc1ef0Fb2FDo2rg'
    }
     r=requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/8sdf40620670353460/messages",data=payload,headers=header)
```

to an arduino code so I can send POST request to a discord server using my esp8266.
I tried the ESP8266 HTTP POST exaple of this page: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-nodemcu-http-get-post-arduino/ , but it didn't work. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Just a side note for the next time: Make sure that **before** you post a question, you removed all sensitive data such as IP addresses, usernames, passwords, tokens etc. as they can be used by malicious users.

Comment: Post your own code, not a tutorial, we don't know how you adopt the code in the tutorial to fit your application. Also, "don't work" does not describe the problem your facing, does it complied, if yes, what kind of the error or response you get?